# How do you perform an ion exchange of a monovalent cation with Br- counterion to a divalent or trivalent anion?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, ionic-compounds

I tried to react an organic compound I have synthesized containing a di-N substituted imidazole bromide salt with Ag3PO4 with water at room temp to try to replace the Bromide with PO4(3-). I dont think the reaction worked based on elemental analysis.

What is the best way to perform this ion exchange? Im thinking of trying to charge Amberlite IRA400 with sulfuric acid or phosphoric acid and using that resin to exchange the Br- ions. Would that work?

**Edited to add picture of sulfate salt form of the compound:
[image: di-N Substituted Imidazole Sulfate Salt]

Comment: I think the issue is with your cation - not terribly tolerant of things like silver, perhaps.

Answer (score -1):

If the initial monovalent cation is called $\ce{M^+}$, coupled with an anion $\ce{Br-}$, it may react with $\ce{Ag3PO4}$ in a reaction like $$\ce{3 M+ + 3 Br- + Ag3PO4 -> 3 AgBr + 3 M+ + PO4^{3-}}$$ Depending on the nature of the ion $\ce{M+}$, the final group of ions $\ce{M+ + PO4^{3-}}$ may form an insoluble precipitate $\ce{M3PO4}$. It is not necessary to use an ion exchange resin like Amberlite.